# Center a <ul> list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, centering

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem, but nothing has worked for me so far. I hope I could get some help.

I'm trying to get a normal `<ul>` list to center on the page. The way I've been thinking to solve this is by embedding the list inside a div, and then simply center the div by using `margin: 0 auto;`.
But my problem is that the list seems to take, by default, 100% width of its parent.
So how can I adjust the actual list width to be as long as the longest list-item?

Here is an illustration of what I am trying to do:
[image]

***OR, alternatively (I'm okay with either solution):***

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Post the code you tried that didn't work please.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: @Chris - Another option is to use `display: table; + margin: auto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the width to the longest item add `display: inline-block;` to your ul element

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQZ78/)

Answer (score 1):

The HTML

> ```
> <h1>title </h1>
> <li> list item 1 </li> 
> <li> list item item 2 </li> 
> <li> list item item item 3 </li> 
> <li> list item 4 </li>
> ```

And the CSS

> ```
> h1, li{
>
>     text-align:center; 
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. This made the 2nd layout possible. Can't believe I missed something that simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to adjust the display property of the ul to `inline-block' like so:

You also have to align the text of the ul element left so that it isn't centered.

And one last thing.  Unordered lists have a lot of padding that may throw off the centering.  So I removed the padding to make it better centered.  You may want to adjust the padding to fit your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/k84Rz/

```
#centeredDiv {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#centeredDiv ul {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `display: table;` + `margin: auto`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZA8ZB/2/)

```
ul{
    border: 1px solid red;    
    display: table;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve something like the first illustrations use `width: fit-contents` to limit the width if the list item. Add `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` to center the item.

```css
li {
    width: fit-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```